# Measuring orthogonal distance of line from point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, geometry, line, length

I am fairly new to QGIS.

I'm trying to measure the distance between points in a point Layer P and the end of lines in a line layer L. In L there are two categories (attributes) of lines, L1 and L4. Connecting pieces of L1 and L4 will always end at a point P, but they may be segmentes (meaning 2 parts L1 may connect to a part of L4 and after that a part L1 again before reaching a point P).

**The task is** to measure the distance from any point P along the L1 and L4 segments up to a distance of 500 meters. Thereafter I need to separate everything within the 500 meter margin from everything outside the 500 meters. A buffer will not do the job, since the distance is to be measured along the lines.

I got stuck very early on in this process.

[image: This is the situation described.]

Comment: The question is not 100% clear to me, but asking for clarification would probably be pointless as this is an old question and the user does not seem to be active any more on GIS SE. However, very probably the problem could be solved using one of the network analysis tools like `shortest path` or `service area`: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html